# How to apply BucketPolicy (LifecycleConfiguration) to an existing bucket using CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have several buckets that are created using console and I want to apply How to apply LifecycleConfiguration to those existing buckets, is it possible if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to update existing resources with CloudFormation.

If you want to apply lifecycle policies, you can either recreate the buckets with CloudFormation and specify the [`LifecycleConfiguration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig) property or use the [console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html)/[CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/set-lifecycle-cli.html) to update your existing buckets.